# How to bulk insert into SQL Server from Excel by query

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulk

```
BULK INSERT dbo.bulkins 
FROM "C:\BulkDataFile.csv" 
WITH 
    (FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Error:

> Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\BulkDataFile.csv" does not exist.

How to fix it?

Comment: Well - which part of **does not exist** do you not understand? It seems that file just isn't there - *how to fix it?* - put the file where you expect it to be ..... and if this is a *remote* SQL Server, the file must be on the **remote machine's** `C:\` drive - not your local PC's `C:\` drive......

Comment: Also the excel file should be explicitly saved as .csv file.

Comment: @Marc_s **please** add that as the answer so this won't show up in answered.

Answer (score 3):

The error message seems crystal clear: "the file ... does not exist" ...

So it seems that this file you're trying to use to do your `BULK INSERT` just isn't there.

*How to fix it?* Simple: just put the file where you expect it to be, and run your code again.

And if this is a **remote SQL Server**, the file must be on the **remote machine's** `C:\` drive - not your local PC's `C:\` drive ...

Comment: Is there a way to bulk load data from a local file then?  I've succeeded in loading row by row, but it's too slow.  And copying the file to the server would not be allowed.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek: **no** - your remote SQL Server **cannot** access your local drive - and that's a *good thing!* You need to put your file either directly onto the server's file system, or onto a storage drive where the SQL Server has access to.

Comment: Ok.  But how come I can load the same file from my local machine using SSIS? (I'd prefer to use SSIS, but the code I'm maintaining is in Excel VBA).  This is probably better as a separate question.